# Finding jobs generated by Job DSL plugin programmatically

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

We have a mix of DSL-seeded and manually created jobs on our Jenkins server.
I'd like to find all jobs **NOT** generated by DSL (or all generated by DSL at any time in the past).
I found no indication in job's config.xml that it was generated by DSL.
So, is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have the same problem as you.

I wonder how the link "Seed job" within the generated job is created. I don't see it in all of the generated jobs, either.

Unfortunately, I didn't get very far with my research.

In the script console, I listed the methods for one of my jobs (let's call it `foo`) :

```
Jenkins.instance.getItems().each {
  if (it.getName() == 'foo') {
    println it
    it.class.getMethods().each { method ->
      println method
    }
  }
};
```

However, I didn't see any methods containing `jobdsl` there.

I found a file `$JENKINS_HOME/javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.xml` that contains generated job names and their seed jobs. But I don't know whether there is an official JobDSL API for reading it.

So... if you find more information, I'd be glad to know - good luck!

Comment: I'd like to find out too! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, here's how my colleague did it: Every job that generates other job can tell you what jobs it generated. So, if you take all the jobs in your Jenkins that exist, remove all generator jobs and all jobs that the generator jobs generated - then you get the non-generated jobs!